# i posted array as string format but it will not get by laravel 5.3.but in laravel 5.2 it works fine

Tags: php

I worked in laravel 5.2 and I've done the following code, it executed successfully. But in laravel 5.3 it will produce

> "Trying to get no property object error"

when i am trying to get particular column value and also the posted value is empty.plz help me.

```
$multiple_country_name=Input::get('multiple_country_name');
$multiple_desination=Input::get('multiple_destination');
$multiple_from=Input::get('multiple_from');
$multiple_to=Input::get('multiple_to');

$multiple_country_name1=explode(',', $multiple_country_name);
$multiple_desination1=explode(',',$multiple_desination);
$multiple_from1=explode(',', $multiple_from);
$multiple_to1=explode(',', $multiple_to);

for($i=0;$i<count($multiple_desination1);$i++)
{
    $traveling_details=new traveling_details();
    $traveling_details->travel_request_id=$travel_request->id;
    $traveling_details->ticket_required=$ticket;
    $country=country::where('name','=',$multiple_country_name1[$i])->first()->id;  
    $traveling_details->country_id=$country;
    $traveling_details->destination=$multiple_desination1[$i];
    $traveling_details->from_date=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($multiple_from1[$i]));
    //$to_date= date("Y-m-d", strtotime($multiple_to1[$i]));
    $traveling_details->to_date=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($multiple_to1[$i]));
    $traveling_details->save();

 }
```

Comment: try to print any one input value whether you get value or not .

Comment: Show us the REAL and FULL error message. Then we can attempt an **answer** rather than a **guess** Its also useful to indicate WHICH LINE the error message is from as obviously you have not posted the complete file. ___Help us to help you___

Comment: i passed the the multiple_country_name as UK,US format and exploded it in controller.but it will give empty value.how to solve it.thus all